# How to get Minitest to test in Parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have tried adding this to minitest: `parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)` but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I have some very back stock CRUD tests and they take 2-3 minutes each for just a single controller:

```
Running 7 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Started with run options --seed 2895

  7/7: [=======================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:03:06, Time: 00:03:06

Finished in 186.22311s
7 tests, 11 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

This seems to be a LONG time for some basic test.  I added `parallelize_me!` to my tests and they ran instantly then I realized that they were passing 100% of the tests even if there were underlying failures.  The documentation on this seems week and I am not finding much from searching etc.

I can't even see where you set that parallelization threshold?

Answer (score 0):

The parallelization threshold is 50 but this test contains only 7 tests so it will not parallelize. You can lower the threshold:

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, threshold: 5)
```